# Does a Middle Ground Exist? (Unit Testing vs. Integration Testing)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing

Consider an implementation of the Repository Pattern (or similar). I'll try to keep the example/illustration as succinct as possible:

```
interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        // Some logic to add the entity to the repository here.
    }
}
```

In this particular implementation, the Repository is defined by an interface IRepository to have one method which adds an entity to the repository, thus making Repository dependant upon the generic type T (also, the Repository must be implicitly dependant upon another type TDataAccessLayer, since the abstraction is the entire point of the Repository Pattern. This dependency, however, is not currently readily available). At this point, from what I understand so far, I have two options: Unit Testing and Integration Testing.

Where Integration Testing may be assumed to have a greater number of moving parts, I would much rather initially Unit Test in order to as least verify a baseline functionality. However, without creating some sort of "entity" property (of generic type T), I can see no way of asserting that any logic is actually performed within the Add() method of the Repository implementation.

Is there, perhaps, a middle ground somewhere between Unit Testing and Integration Testing which allows (through Reflection or some other means) to verify that specific points of execution have been reached within a tested unit?

The only explanation I've come up with for this particular issue is to further abstract the Data Access Layer from the repository, resulting in the Add() method accepting not only an entity argument but also a Data Access argument. This seems to me like it might defeat the purpose of the Repository Pattern, however, since the consumer of the Repository must now know about the Data Access Layer.

**With regard to request for examples:**

(1) And in regard to Unit Testing, I'm not sure something like a Repository could actually be Unit Tested with my understanding of current testing techniques. Because a Repository is an abstraction (wrapper) around a specific Data Access Layer, it seems that the only method of verification would be an Integration Test? (Granted, a Repository Interface may not be tied to any specific DAL, but any implemented Repository must surely be tied to a specific DAL implementation, therefore the need to be able to test that the Add() method actually performs some work).

(2) And in regard to Integration Testing, the test, as I understand the technique, would verify the Add() method performing work by actually calling the Add() method (which should add a record to the repository) and then check to see that the data was actually added to the repository (or perhaps database in a specific scenario). This may look something like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Add()
{
    Repository<Int32> repository = new Repository<Int32>();
    Int32 testData = 10;

    repository.Add(testData);

    // Intended to illustrate the point succinctly. Perhaps the repository Get() method would not
    // be called (and a DBCommand unrelated to the repository issued instead). However, assuming the
    // Get() method to have been previously verified, this could work.
    Assert.IsTrue(testData == repository.Get(testData));
}
```

So, in this instance, assuming the repository is a wrapper around some database logic layer, the database is actually hit twice during the test (once during insert, and once during retrieve).

Now, what I could see being useful, would be a technique for verifying that a certain execution path is taken during runtime. An example could be that if a non-null reference is passed in, verify execution path A is taken, and if a null reference is passed in, verify execution path B is taken. Also, perhaps one could verify that particular LINQ query was to be executed. Therefore, the database is never actually hit during the test (allowing prototyping and development of an implementation without any actual DAL in place).

Comment: Where exactly do you draw the line between "Unit test" and "Integration test" here? Let's say you want to unit test the "Add" method - can you give an example how a unit test should look like, how an integration test should look differently from that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? A concrete implementation? One train of thought to follow: if you were using TDD, you wouldn't _have_ a concrete implementation without unit tests. So, asking yourself what functions you want your implementation to implement becomes equivalent to asking which tests do you want it to pass.

Comment: @John Saunders To an extent, I agree with what you are saying regarding TDD. I've added some more information that should hopefully better define the issue. I'm just not sure the development of something like a Repository could be driven by Unit Tests currently.

Comment: @Brad: I'll look at your method, but FYI, I've found very little that can't be created via TDD.

Comment: @John Saunders It could just be a lack of understanding on my part. I just haven't seen a way to perform the sorts of tests I'm attempting to perform without actually running Integration Tests.

Comment: @Brad: then, chances are, you're trying to do the wrong kind of tests. That's why I asked you "What exactly are you trying to test". I presume you're testing in order to prevent bugs. What kinds of bug are you trying to prevent?

Comment: @John Saunders I appreciate your interest. For example, suppose I want to make sure that entities with `null` references are never added (for instance, I just `return` within the Add() method upon detection of a `null` reference). The `return` would represent execution path A, while an add to the repository would represent execution path B. Seems like this is something an Add() method might reasonably handle, rather than testing for null references outside the method upon every call. Perhaps not?

Comment: @Brad: that's not an execution path. It's a behavior. `Add(null)` adds nothing. Your repository needs a retrieval method or `Count` method in order to test that.

Comment: @John Saunders Ah, okay, now we're getting somewhere. I'll take a look into behaviors and try to find some information on Behavior Driver Development. This could be exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: @Brad: sorry, not Behavior with a capital "B". I mean behavior in the sense of an externally-visible behavior of the object. You can observe whether adding a "null" throws an exception, or adds a null, or what, but you should have no interest in _how_ that is accomplished.

Comment: @John Saunders Hm. I guess I'm just having a difficult time wrapping my head around this one. I considered returning a value of some sort indicating whether an object was added or not, but was informed that tests conducted in this manner really proved nothing more than that the method could return the expected value (i.e. that the test could not confirm the method was actually adding an object to the repository or perhaps taking an alternate route). This is what makes me think that Integration Tests are the only way to currently work with this scenario. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: @John Saunders A special thanks to you for pointing me in the right directory with behaviors. I was reading over some material relating to the issue and all of a sudden it just clicked. By abstracting away just enough of the Data Access Layer to instatiate it within the Repository's constructor I am free to validate specific method calls on a mocked DAL object. (in my case a LINQ to SQL DataContext, using IDataContext). I'll leave the question open for a couple days. If you'd like to add an answer, I'll be more than happy to accept.

Comment: @Brad: I'm afraid that a complete answer from me would not help you. I do not develop against patterns like the Repository Pattern. I asked earlier "what bugs do you expect to find (or prevent) by testing"? I have reached the point as a developer where I don't have bugs in simple code like `Add` or `Remove` or `GetById` or whatever. I spend no more time testing such code than I spend testing that a button click works - tests are intended to find bugs and prevent their recurrence, so I don't test what will never break.

Comment: @Brad: this is in sharp contrast to testing what _will_ break. Example: I just maintained a SP that broke once per fiscal year - needed the DB to be manually initialized every year. In a hurry so didn't test the change. Once QA found the bug, I went back and wrote a failing unit test, then made it pass by fixing the bug. I didn't use mocks, though - I ran the whole thing under a transaction and rolled it back at the end of the test. Much faster than refactoring straightforward DAL code to permit mocking.

Comment: @John Saunders Okay, that's fine, just figured I'd give you the option. Once I've got a working solution in hand I'll answer the question so that others may benefit. I suppose this question has been more about what to unit test and how to go about it than a matter of whether or not an InsertOnSubmit will fail.

Comment: @Brad: you may be amused by "[Am I Unit Testing or Integration Testing my Stored Procedures?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/81801/am-i-unit-testing-or-integration-testing-my-stored-procedures)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing the testing of an implementation detail rather than fulfillment of the requirements of a pattern by an implementor of the pattern. It doesn't matter if "specific points of execution" have been reached within the tested unit, it only matters if the concrete implementor upholds the contract of the interface. It's perfectly acceptable for tests to create a `T` entity for testing purposes, that's what mocks are for.

Comment: Sure, I could mock an entity object, but my issue is then what would I actually assert against in a Unit Test? Calling `repository.Add(someMockObject)` isn't really very useful for me unless I can verify that some action is taken upon `someMockObject`.

Comment: The requirement that the repository must satisfy is persisting the object you added. Testing an "add-only" repository is a futile exercise because you are testing a useless repository. The only way to test an `Add` method on arbitrary repository implementation is to ask it to give back the object you Added.

Comment: This is basically the same thing @JohnSaunders is saying, rather than thinking in dogmatic "test patterns" terms, it's better to think in "proving the implementor does what is it required to do" terms. It doesn't matter if it's "integration" or "unit," it matters that the test is unaware of implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do integration testing you need to use the real database. But if you quickly want to test things you could try an in memory database.
The question is what you can test and what you cannot test. As long as your database access code is db specific you are using an external system (to stay in unit test speak) which you should mock. But since you really want to know if your data ends up in the datbase you need to test against the real database.

But if you use some db abstraction e.g. an ORM mapper you could use the ORM mapper and test if at least the mapping does work correctly. The ORM mapper then could use an in memory datbase for your tests to check if the ORM mapper does work as expected.

If you do not use an ORM mapper and you create an additional db abstraction layer only to have an abstraction so you have code which is executed for the sole purpose to have errors you want to uncover in your true unit tests is not going to make you more productive.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do unit test. Work on integration test only .It is so easy to implement unit test and as much useless it will be especially in a repository pattern. Almost all errors happens on direct dealing with DB and with data logic. Unit tests cannot find such errors. Unless you do a method with a complex calculation with lot of possible outcomes, avoid unit tests altogether. Another benefit is load testing with the same code. The intermediate/temporary solutions you asked about will lead you to nothing.

*What is the user story?*

Get Employee details from DB

*How to finish the task?*

Code and test if Employee details are fetched from DB. Write down all the scenarios you could think of. We are only talking in scenarios (nothing less nothing more).

Integration test or functional test has to deal with DB/source directly. No mocks. So these are the steps. You want to test getEmployee( emp_id). all these 5 steps below are done in a single test method.

1. Drop DB
2. Create DB and populate roles and other infra data
3. Create an employee record with ID (this should not be using the
   repository or working code). You need another code that puts data to
   DB in the test project. Seeding requires a code set.
4. Use this ID and call repository.getEmployee(emp_id)// this is the
   code you wrote and need to be tested

Now Assert()/ Verify if the returned data is correct

This proves that getEmployee() works . Steps until 4 requires you to have code used only by test project. Step 4 calls the application code. What I meant is creating an employee (step 3) should be done by test project code not application code. If there is an application code to create employee (eg: CreateEmployee() or Repository.Add(Employee)) then this should not be used. Same way, when we test CreateEmployee() then GetEmployee() application code should not be used. We should have a test project code for fetching data from a table.

This way there are no mocks! The reason to drop and create DB is to prevent DB from having corrupt data. With our approach, the test will pass no matter how many times we run it.

You talked about scenarios, Did this code get executed or that if condition executed, etc. That need to be verified with input data and output data(from the original source, be it DB or log files).

> An example could be that if a non-null reference is passed in, verify
> execution path A is taken, and if a null reference is passed in,
> verify execution path B is taken.

So you pass in null reference to repository method. Then you call the DB(using your test project code) and check if the error table has an entry. Or upload the log file and check if the error is added there(again using your own test code or a 3rd party component). You might think you are doing a lot of custom code in test project. Actually these are some simple get and put you do once and stays for ever.

And this is a great article discussing the benefits of integration testing over unit testing because ["unit testing kills!"](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/before-you-feed-unit-test-beast-s-a-n-j-ay-mohan) (it says)